# Need to create a list and issue a message depending how often the message should be displayed

Tags: c#, xml, desktop-application

I am creating a program that interacts with a game and I want it to do the following:

1. Get a list of messages from the admins.
2. Let them display how often it is to be displayed

Simple enough right?

I'm not asking for code, just some ideas on how to handle the message and to handle the timing of each message?

Should I use a timer and keep the messages in memory?

I plan on storing this information in an xml file.

My question is more how should I handle displaying the messages on the given times efficiently?

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use [DispatcherTimer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatchertimer.aspx) to achieve that.

`DispatcherTimer` runs on the UI/Dispatcher thread and not on thread pool thread, another reason to use it when you are doing UI operations with timer. Also one can set the priority of the dispatcher thread.

Comment: I looked at this. How would I handle a dynamic number of messages with their own timer?

Comment: you can have a delegate that takes a message and time and returns a new `DispatcherTimer` for that message.